# Printing single quote become weird character in .txt-file

Tags: python, selenium

I used Selenium to scrape some sentences, and then print the result to a .txt-file, but it cannot display `'` but instead some weird character:

Original sentence:

```
I don't think so.
```

in .txt file:

```
I don? think so.
```

I have specified the .txt encoding to "utf-8" already, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the file for writing in "utf-8" for that:

```
with open("file.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file

    file.write("your_text")
```

Hope it helps you!